# Playing Music From PC

Tags: music

I want to be able to listen to songs on my phone via my pc at work.
I want my headphones to be plugged into my pc.
Is there any application that works with Google Play Music on the pc?

Like when you ply an iPhone into itunes and can play music

Thanks

** Edit 20/11/2013

At work we can't stream music. 
Also I'm not guaranteed to be sitting at the same machine so don't want to copy all my songs to the pc each time

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about PC software and isn't related to Android.

Comment: @DanHulme Is there no other way to stream the audio to the PC using an Android app? I'm voting to Leave Open this question.

Comment: What about a DLNA server (e.g. BubbleUPnP) on the Android device, and some DLNA client on the computer? As long as both are connected to the same network, that should do.

Comment: Why would you want any of that? You can stream music from Google Play straight to any PC by logging in through the web interface. The phone doesn't have to be involved at all.

Comment: Do you have a bluetooth device on your pc? 
You probably have one if you have a laptop. Or you could buy a bluetooth dongle through which you can play music from your android device and listen with your pc output(speakers/headphones)

Comment: http://play.google.com/music

Comment: At work we can't stream music. Also I'm not guaranteed to be sitting at the same machine so don't want to copy all my songs to the pc

Answer (score 1):

You have two options, assuming your using a windows pc:

There is this nifty windows app for the pc:

Google Music Desktop Player for Windows:

http://apps.codigobit.info/2011/10/google-music-desktop-player.html

The web UI:

http://play.google.com/music

https://play.google.com/music/listen

Just a matter of preference, the web UI is easy & accessible from any pc with a internet connection or the app if you prefer a more permanent solution on like your daily pc or something you use frequently...

Comment: I'm in Australia this unfortunately this doesn't help. Also I can't stream music

Answer (score 0):

If you have uploaded your songs from your Android device unto Google Play Music (not sure if it does this automaticly) then you are able to play the music by logging into http://music.google.com from your PC.

The sweet side effect of this is that it doesn't drain your Android's battery. :)